# React Native: React-Navigation Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I am currently learning React Native and was having some issue with React-navigation.
What I am trying to do is switch screen when the "button" is being pressed.
In the "button", I have:

`onPress={() =>
  navigate('Home')}`

I have `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` before the return statement.

When I run it, I am getting "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.
I guess it is I have to place `this.props.navigation` somewhere.

Here are my two files:
"IntroPageFive" is the one that has the button and "react-navigation".

I would like to go to "IntroPageOne" when the button is being clicked.

Code for "IntroPageFive":

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Linking, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import PlaceholderImage from '../images/placeholder_thumbnail.png';
import SignInFooter from './signInFooter';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import IntroPageOne  from './introPageOne';


const App = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: IntroPageOne },
});

class IntroPageFive extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { 
      headerTextStyle, 
      thumbnailStyle, 
      viewStyle, 
      subTextStyle, 
      mainTextSection, 
      footerSectionStyle, 
      startButtonStyle, 
      startButtonTextStyle, 
      signInButtonStyle ,
      signInButtonTextStyle
    } = styles;

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View style={viewStyle}>
        <Image style={thumbnailStyle} source={require('../images/placeholder_thumbnail.png')} />
        <View style={mainTextSection}>
          <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Take A Ride For</Text>
          <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Your Favorite Car!</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() =>
              navigate('Home')
            }

            style={startButtonStyle}
          >
            <Text style={startButtonTextStyle}>LET'S GET STARTED</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={footerSectionStyle}>
          <SignInFooter />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default IntroPageFive;
```

Here is the code for "IntroPageOne":

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Linking } from 'react-native';
import PlaceholderImage from '../images/placeholder_thumbnail.png';

import SignInFooter from './signInFooter';


const IntroPageOne = () => {
  const { headerTextStyle, thumbnailStyle, viewStyle, subTextStyle } = styles;

  return (
    
  <View style={viewStyle} >
    <Image style={thumbnailStyle} source={require('../images/placeholder_thumbnail.png')} />
    <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Forget Everything You</Text>
    <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Know About Making</Text>
    <Text style={headerTextStyle}>Deals For Your Car</Text>
    <Text style={subTextStyle}>Deal negotiation powered by AI</Text>

    <SignInFooter />
  </View>
  );
};
};

export default IntroPageOne;
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you have to pass 'navigation' into 'IntroPageFive' somewhere.

Comment: Also, if you want to go to 'IntroPageOne' when your button is clicked, you should put that name to navigate(), and not 'Home'.

Comment: You don't seem to put `IntroPageFive` in the `createStackNavigator`, so you will not get the `navigation` prop to your component.